# showIn Causes Form Validation

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I am using kendo-ui's SPA to create a client-side CRUD screen. One of the features is to allow for users to change their password and so I setup the following template:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="user-change-password">
    <div class="hpanel hblue">
        <div class="panel-heading hbuilt">
            <div class="panel-tools">
                <a class="showhide"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
            </div>
            Change Password for <span data-bind="text: userViewModel.UserName"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <form class="container-fluid" id="user-change-password-form">
                <a class="k-button btn-xs m-b-md" data-bind="attr: {href: userHref}">
                    <i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>
                    Go Back
                </a>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="change-password">New Password</label>
                    <input id="change-password" type="password" class="k-textbox" required="required" data-bind="value: password" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="change-password-confirm">New Password Confirmation</label>
                    <input id="change-password-confirm" type="password" class="k-textbox" required="required" data-bind="value: passwordConfirmation" />
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="k-button" data-bind="click: formSubmission">
                            <i class="fa fa-save"></i>
                            Save
                        </button>
                        <button type="reset" class="k-button">
                            <i class="fa fa-undo"></i>
                            Reset
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

The issue with this is that it appears as if whenever the router hits the route calls the showIn method, it causes the form to attempt to validate (causing the inputs to be outlined in red). This is the code that I'm using for the route:

```
router.route("/edit/:userId/change-password", function (userId) {
    _viewModel.changePassword.set("userId", userId);
    layout.showIn(".layout-content", changePasswordInterface);
});
```

How can I make it so that whenever the user visits the route, it does not try to submit the form without using another third party library?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Kendo's SPA, but I'd like to point out that validation firing doesn't mean the form is getting submitted. By default, single fields are validated when they're [blurred](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/validator/configuration/validateonblur).  
I would check how the views are created and viewModels are bound. 
If the form is re-using old inputs that had validation errors in the past, you may need to call [hideMessages](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/validator/methods/hidemessages)

Comment: @GaloisGirl just to clarify, I'm not using the kendo-ui validator. I'm just using the HTML required attribute. But this could be an acceptable solution to use the kendoValidator.

Comment: Hope the form submission has preventDefault().
You can try, I am not sure it will work :    
 Add validator after the layout is added in the route.
 var validator = $("#<form_id>").kendoValidator().data("kendoValidator")

Comment: Also could you check that form submission is fired, and not the blur event.